# How to parse GA4 Measurement Protocol (collect?v=2) POST request URLs?

Tags: parsing, google-analytics, measurement-protocol, google-analytics-4

## Objective

- I am developing a Chrome DevTools extension to display data sent to GA4.
- Example output: https://github.com/temelm/tealman/blob/357c3a5472cc6737781268499f49802530d833cc/store-listing/screenshots/2.png
- I do not want to put any company's GA4 tracking/measurement ID on Stack Overflow. Hence, to see an example POST request I am trying to parse: 1. Open DevTools => 2. Select Network tab => 3. Filter by `collect?v=2` => 4. Visit https://www.ocado.com/search?entry=nutella => 5. Slightly scroll down
- You should be able to see a network hit with both query string parameters and request payload.
- I am trying parse this data and display it nicely to assist debugging.
- Code currently failing to do this can be found at: https://github.com/temelm/tealman/blob/357c3a5472cc6737781268499f49802530d833cc/src/panel/scripts/GA4.js
- Functions of interest: `groupData()`, `parseData()`, `getParameterAliasAndGroup()`, `formatProduct()`

## Problem

- Main problem, as far as I can see, is when multiple GA4 hits are sent close to each other, GA4 batches and sends them together.
- I am struggling to understand how to go parse GA4 hits which carry data for multiple events.
- I was able to do the same exercise for other providers including GA3 for which documentation is brilliant.
- I was unable to find anything useful reading the [GA4 Measurement Protocol Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference?client_type=gtag).
- This problem causes the data displayed to be incomplete / incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Standalone GA4 hits are POST requests with query string parameters.
- Batched GA4 hits are POST requests with query string parameters and payload.
- Splitting payload text by one or more whitespace characters will return an array of strings where each string represents the data associated with a batched GA4 event.

  - Example: `postDataText.split(/\s+/)`